# Invisible cursor over panel in Gnome 3.14

Tags: gnome, mouse, 14.10, cursor, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed Gnome 3.14 from PPA under Ubuntu 14.10 and, upon rebooting, the mouse cursor only shows over applications. Moving the mouse over the gnome panel hides the cursor. Same thing when opening the dashboard. When I launch Gnome Tweak, the "Cursor" dropdown selection is disabled.

I have been installing up-to-date Gnome for a while and I'm not sure how I can fix this. Most "resolutions" for this issue dates quite a while back.

Any idea how this can be resolved?

Thanks!

### ** Edit **

I have installed a cursor theme under `~/.icons` and, while I now have a cursor over the gnome panel, the cursor theme is not applied. And I believe that the mouse cursor I see over applications is X11's default cursors (the ones we used to have ions ago with Linux).

### ** Update **

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxfa2fXJ1Wc) youtube video, I got the cursor working again... except in Google Chrome.